# Get Error, Success Logs On powershell script Importing Bulk AD user

Tags: active-directory, powershell

This Script will the best Bulk AD user creation script  for me, if I am able to Generate success and error logs.

This script just requires FirstName and Lastname on Csv that cut offs few minutes. Need help generating logs such as list of successfully created user and account already exists or failed to create.

```
$Users=Import-csv c:\users.csv 

ForEach($User in $Users)
{
    $FullName = $User.FirstName + " " + $User.LastName
    $SAM = $User.FirstName.Substring(0,1) + $User.LastName #example John snow will be Jsnow
    #$Sam=$User.FirstName+$User.LastName example john snow will be Johnsnow
    #$Sam=$User.FirstName example john snow will be John
    #$Sam= $User.firstName + "." + $User.lastName example john snow will be John.snow
     $dnsroot = '@' + (Get-ADDomain).dnsroot
    $UPN = $SAM + "$dnsroot "
    $OU="CN=users, DC=Domain,DC=COM"
    $email=$Sam + "$dnsroot "

New-ADUser -Name $FullName -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString “Password!1234” -AsPlainText -force) -GivenName $User.FirstName  -Path $OU -SamAccountName $SAM -Surname $User.LastName  -UserPrincipalName $UPN -EmailAddress $Email -Enabled $TRUE}
Write-Host "created $FullName"
```

Comment: Read [about_Try_Catch_Finally](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847793.aspx) and think more about generating user names if there are `John Snow`, `Jane Snow` and `Jim Snow`. Read [Out-File](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/13d09dc8-2398-4d73-9449-1d01eb4e7808(v=wps.630).aspx) and [Tee-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=294019) about _genarating logs_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Users=Import-csv c:\users.csv 
$failedUsers = @()
$usersAlreadyExist =@()
$successUsers = @()
$VerbosePreference = "Continue"
$LogFolder = "C:\temp"
ForEach($User in $Users)
{
   $FullName = $User.FirstName + " " + $User.LastName
   $SAM = $User.FirstName.Substring(0,1) + $User.LastName
   $dnsroot = '@' + (Get-ADDomain).dnsroot
   $UPN = $SAM + "$dnsroot "
   $OU="CN=users, DC=Domain,DC=COM"
   $email=$Sam + "$dnsroot "

try {
    if (!(get-aduser -Filter {samaccountname -eq "$SAM"})){
        New-ADUser -Name $FullName -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString “Password!1234” -AsPlainText -force) -GivenName $User.FirstName  -Path $OU -SamAccountName $SAM -Surname $User.LastName  -UserPrincipalName $UPN -EmailAddress $Email -Enabled $TRUE
        Write-Verbose "[PASS] Created $FullName"
        $successUsers += $FullName
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "[WARNING] Samaccount for username [$($FullName)] already exists"
        $usersAlreadyExist += $FullName
    }
}
catch {
    Write-Warning "[ERROR]Can't create user [$($FullName)] : $_"
    $failedUsers += $FullName
}
}
if ( !(test-path $LogFolder)) {
    Write-Verbose "Folder [$($LogFolder)] does not exist, creating"
    new-item $LogFolder -Force 
}

Write-verbose "Writing logs"
$failedUsers | out-file -FilePath  $LogFolder\FailedUsers.log -Force -Verbose
$usersAlreadyExist | out-file -FilePath  $LogFolder\usersAlreadyExist.log -Force -Verbose
$successUsers | out-file -FilePath  $LogFolder\successUsers.log -Force -Verbose
```

Comment: You are awesome Sergei thanks, we can also get sucess logs, actually usersAlreadyExist.log is not required i see that all the logs are written on failed users

Comment: added success logging

Comment: also added strings because excel file containing list of users can be of any format sometimes all caps. 

$User.FirstName = $User.FirstName.substring(0,1).toupper()+$User.FirstName.substring(1).tolower()
    $User.LastName = $User.LastName.substring(0,1).toupper()+$User.LastName.substring(1).tolower()